# Opening files in electron.js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, electron

I want to make electronjs text editor app and i want be able to open new window with a script that was written inside of the editor. For example, i have small script in  my editor and when i press open in browser, it opens and loads in browser window. Here is part of my code.

```
function createWindow() {
  // Create the browser window.
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
  });

  // and load the index.html of the app.
  mainWindow.loadURL(
    url.format({
      pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'),
      protocol: 'file:',
      slashes: true,
    })
  );

  // Open the DevTools.
  mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();

  // Emitted when the window is closed.
  mainWindow.on('closed', function() {
    // Dereference the window object, usually you would store windows
    // in an array if your app supports multi windows, this is the time
    // when you should delete the corresponding element.
    mainWindow = null;
  });

  // trigger autoupdate check
  autoUpdater.checkForUpdates();
}
```

My button in  html:

```
<button id="openBrowser"><img src="img/16x16/diskette.png"/>Open in Browser </button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to open it in an external window, you'll need to import shell

`const shell = require('electron').shell`

Then you'll need to use the openExternal method of shell

`shell.openExternal('yourpathhere')`

Is that what you're after?

https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/browser-window.md

Comment: Whoops, I made a mistake so I edited it. I had written `BrowserWindow` where I meant `openExternal`. Sorry for any confusion